# Angular timezone CDT/CST issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having date in UTC format which i need to convert to CST.

UTC to CDT difference 5 hrs ahead

UTC to CTC difference 6hrs ahead

My UTC Date is '2016-09-07T05:00:00Z'

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

<p>Date = {{ today | date:'longDate':'CST' }}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = '2016-09-07T05:00:00Z'
});
</script>
```

This converts my date to

Date = September 6, 2016

but it is actually day light saving period.
If i replace CST to CDT then it works fine for this but will fail for other months when day light saving is not there.

Any solution so that it automatically detect which timezone CTC/CDT needs to be applied .

Comment: This similar issue might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68389436/1974681

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handling dates and timezones is using Moment Timezone where you can provide the timezone and it also accounts for the daylight saving period.

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-ambiguous-inputs/

Comment: i don't want to change much on my code .looking for some solution through angular only

Comment: Unfortunately I think you might need to. Check closely [Date filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). I don't think it would provide the kind of capability you want. Using moment-timezone wouldn't need much changes though.